# Safari horizontal scroll

Tags: css, safari, scroll, vertical-scrolling

My problem happens on large desktop screen.

You can have a sample of the problem right here ==> http://www.pricebreak.it/#!explore/Sports-et-loisirs/17-AB-Prince-Pro-Banc-a-abdominaux

Site is in two parts.

The left panel for the menu, CSS is :

```
#panel-structure{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px; 
    left:0px;
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    z-index:15;
    background-color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
}
```

and a container on the right :

```
#content-structure{
    margin:0 0 0 300px;
    display:block;
    overflow: auto;
    /*position: relative;
    top:0; left:300px;*/
    height:0px;
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 310px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 310px);
    width: -o-calc(100% - 310px);
    width: calc(100% - 310px);
}
```

It might be useful to have the body css also:

```
body{
    line-height:160%;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 100%; max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*height:100%;
    max-height:100%;*/
}
```

The jQuery plugin mCustomScroll bar deal with the VERTICAL scroll.

If you open the previous link in Chrome, Opera, Firefox you'll see the vertical scrollbar on your screen and you will NOT have horizontal scroll. Perfect :)

If you open in Safari, you will not see the vertical scrollbar because you have to scroll horizontally to see it...

I'm struggling with this for hours now...

I tried to console the width and, for example, if body.outerWidth is 1500 then I'll have the panel.outerWidth to 300 and content.outerWidth to 1200.

I just DON'T understand why Safari add some horizontal scroll...

Any help would be welcome ! Thanks a lot !

## Edit 08/28:

I tried to change #content-structure to :

```
#content-structure{
    /*margin:0 0 0 300px;
    display:block;
    overflow: auto;*/
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:300px;
    /*position: relative;
    top:0; left:300px;*/
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 310px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 310px);
    width: -o-calc(100% - 310px);
    width: calc(100% - 310px);
    max-width: -moz-calc(100% - 310px);
    max-width: -webkit-calc(100% - 310px);
    max-width: -o-calc(100% - 310px);
    max-width: calc(100% - 310px);
}
```

but still this scroll...

Comment: Be careful, calc is not supported in Safari 5.1, it is supported from Safari 6.1 and greater versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two inputs that have `width: 100%;` and `padding: 10px 0;`

Add this:

```
#breaker-data_8, #breaker-data_9 {
    box-sizing: border-box
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

And problem solved :)

**UPDATE:**

I got what causes your problem. You may be seeing it from Safari 5.1 where `calc` is not supported.

In this piece of CSS:

```
#content-structure{
    margin:0 0 0 300px;
    display:block;
    overflow: auto;
    /*position: relative;
    top:0; left:300px;*/
    height:0px;
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 310px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 310px);
    width: -o-calc(100% - 310px);
    width: calc(100% - 310px);
}
```

If you remove the `calc` property you will have the same in Chrome and Firefox, you will have to scroll horizontally to see the vertical scroll.

As I said before `calc` is not supported in Safari 5.1, it is supported from Safari 6.1 and greater versions so instead of setting the `width` with calc, try to do give it a width in pixels or if you want it to be `100% - 310px` do it by javascript.

Add this to your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(window).width() > 1024)
        $('#content-structure').width( $('body').width() - 310 );
    else
        $('#content-structure').width('98%');

    $(window).resize(function(){
        if( $(window).width() > 1024)
            $('#content-structure').width( $('body').width() - 310 );
        else
            $('#content-structure').width('98%');
    });
});
```

The `$(window).resize` is there to make sure that when you resize the window your styles still aplies and modifies to the new window width

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve this Safari problem... I still have horizontal scroll.

Comment: @pierreaurelemartin I missed a semicolon but I asume that you wrote it right. I'll try fix it, what version of safari do you have? Do you see it from Mac, Linux or Windows?

Comment: @pierreaurelemartin see the update, I got your answer

Comment: @pierreaurelemartin see last update, I tested the script and everything worked fine :)

Comment: Hi @Carlos , sorry i missed your update. I fixed the problem and funniest is that I was not working on this so I have no idea how I did that. Anyway, I'll follow your recommendation and do the calc on JS side. I'll be back to check it with you :)

Comment: @pierreaurelemartin Alright. I tested the JS in your webside and it worked so I am pretty sure it will solve that issue for you. Don't forget to mark the answer if that fixed your problem :)